# Active Record - Read query not giving correct result if another record is created at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, race-condition

I have a table (*events*) in which records are created based on some triggers.
Before creating an event, I look at some N number of past records and accordingly, update data of current event.

Example: Each event record contains a rating column. Whenever a new record is supposed to be created, I fetch last N events and check if there is an event of rating 'X'. If any such record exists, I change rating value of current event to 'Y'.

```
def create(event)
    events = fetch_last_n_events_of_rating_x
    event.rating = Y if events.present?
    event.save
end
```

The issue that is happening is, I got 2 create requests at the same time. 1st one got created succesfully. When the 2nd was created, it could not find any event in *fetch_last_n_events_of_rating_x*. Due to this, the rating of 2nd event which was supposed to get set to Y, did not happen.

I want to understand, what is the correct way of implementing this? How can I avoid such scenarios?
I cannot use database constraints here, as I am not updating the same record. I am using previous records while creating new ones.

Comment: I would consider a) locking the table for write request during the operation. This obviously doesn't work when there are many concurrent write operations in high frequency. Or b) inserting the data with a raw SQL statement that allows setting the value of that column depending on a sub query that determines the condition during the write operation.

Comment: I am a bit unclear on the overall intent but what you are describing is a psuedo race condition. Maybe try searching this term along with ruby on rails and see if any of the guidance there suits you?

Comment: Not really clear on why the second event did not get a rating. Why could it not find an event in fetch_last_n_events_of_rating_x? I agree that the subquery might be a useful way to go, FWIW (and in general Rails sometimes creates very bad queries in the first place). But if the only issue is that the last N events sometimes excludes records because a new one was added, it's not clear to me why there is a problem. I suspect some transaction logic might be useful here, but it's hard to tell from the info given. And the best answer may well depend on the datastore you're using. More info please?